# Checksum of array elements

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array, checksum

I have a multidimensional array of `Bytes` defined as follows:

```
type
  TRow = array[0..6] of Byte;
var
  All: array[0..19112079] of TRow;
```

Now, I would like to generate a unique checksum of each row the array consists of and save to a file, like so:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 19112079 do
  begin
    Checksum := GenerateChecksum(All[I]);
    Writeln(F, Checksum);
  end;
end;
```

What should I do about the `GenerateChecksum()` function? I've tried `xor` and `CRC32`, but they are not really suitable for this task, as they return duplicated values. I'd like to generate a **unique** checksum for each row.

**EDIT**
Oh, the checksum should be computed in such way that it allows to compare rows. I would like to take two checksums of different rows and tell whether one of them is greater than the other, lesser than the other, or equal. Is there a chance of achieving something like that?

**EDIT2**
Example data in two adjacent rows:

```
Row x - 1: 120, 444, 323, 984, 1024, 76, 130
Row x:     120, 444, 323, 984, 1024, 76, 222
Row x + 1: 120, 444, 323, 984, 1024, 76, 121
. . .
Row x + n: 120, 444, 323, 984, 6333, 33, 935
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what version of Delphi are you using ?

Comment: Delphi XE2 Update 3. I used `Writeln` just to illustrate the process. :)

Comment: checksum value(limit size) generate from many possible data. it can't be unique

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with your question, but 19112079 seems like a good candidate for a constant :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data just sounds incoherent to me. You defined an `array[0..6] of byte`, but in your example of data, you have values outside the byte range, i.e. 0..255, like 444, 323, 1024... There is an error somewhere.

Since each row only contains 7 bytes of data, the easiest is to wrap it into an `Int64` value. This is not a crc, but just a typecast. So by definition, you won't have any collision here - this is a perfect hash.

It is some kind of "hash of the poor", but it would be very easy.

```
function HashOf(const Row: TRow): Int64; inline;
begin
  result := PInt64(@Row)^ and $00ffffffffffffff;
end;
```

I've defined the function as `inline` since it will be faster.

You'll have one byte overlapping of memory access for the last `TRow` in your array, but it will work as expected. To avoid this, a slower but safer function:

```
function HashOf(const Row: TRow): Int64;
begin
  result := 0;
  move(Row,result,sizeof(Row));
end;
```

Comment: +1 or HashOf could be var LHash: Int64 absolute Row; result := LHash; (:

Comment: @dorin what about byte number 8? You'd end up with rubbish in there.

Comment: @David yeah, missed that part (:

Comment: @DorinDuminica Yes, I use `absolute` sometimes in such case. But you'll have to use `result := LHash and $00ffffffffffffff;` since the 8th byte will contain garbage. I'm not sure that the `inline` directive will compile the code with the `absolute` keyword just like good old `PInt64(..)^`...  Both `PInt64(..)^` and `absolute` will be faster than the other version (with `move`), in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need to store this in something at least 7 bytes to gain the uniqueness property that you desire. That therefore suggests `UInt64`. Simply copy the 7 bytes of a `TRow` into a `UInt64` and you are done.

```
function PackRow(const Row: TRow): UInt64;
begin
  Result := 0;
  Move(Row, Result, SizeOf(Row));
end;
```

For the ordering part of your requirement you may need to reverse the order of the bytes depending on which end of your row array is most significant.